# JDBC MySQL Connection Error

Tags: mysql, jdbc

I get the following error when trying to make a jdbc connection to a mysql database:

> Attempting to connect to jdbc:mysql://localhost/castel castel castel
>   com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Access denied for user 'castel'@'%' to database 'castel'

I can connect to the database through the command line without a problem using the same credentials. I thought it might be a privilege issue so I ran:

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON mysql.* TO 'castel'@'%'
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: It might be helpful to see your code.

Comment: database name, username, password all the same. sad panda.

Answer (score 0):

OK the problem was completely unrelated to database configuration. It turns out my box had it's iptables configured to forward all traffic on port 3306 to another machine so I wasn't talking to the database that I thought was.